# move element after n:th child in javascript

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to move an element with the class stamp2 so it is after the fifth child. This is what I attempted. The item seems removed.

```
$('.stamp2').remove().after('.section:nth-child(5)');
```

html:

```
<section class="photo small stamp stamp1">..</section>
<section class="photo small stamp stamp2">..</section>
<section class="photo small">..</section>
<section class="photo small">..</section>
<section class="photo small">..</section>
<section class="photo small">..</section>
<section class="photo small">..</section>
<section class="photo small">..</section>
<section class="photo small">..</section>
<section class="photo small">..</section>
<section class="photo small">..</section>
<section class="photo small">..</section>
<section class="photo small">..</section>
<section class="photo small">..</section>
```

Comment: please share the html also

Comment: Try `$('.stamp2').detach().insertAfter('.section:nth-child(5)');`

Comment: _"The item seems removed."_ - So you're saying the item _is_ removed from where it was but isn't inserted where you want it (or anywhere else)?

Comment: @nnnnnn yes! It's not added anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the `.remove()` bit, just use `after()` it will move the node:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NFCbN/)

```
$('section:nth-child(5)').after($('.stamp2'))
```

Comment: the first suggstione adds '.section:nth-child(5)' as a text-sting, not after that element.

Comment: Sorry, short brainfreeze :) `after()` function works in the opposite way, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try [.insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter)

```
$('.stamp2').detach().insertAfter('.section:nth-child(5)')
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove it. Simply use the after function as it will do the trick

```
$('.stamp2').after($('.section:nth-child(5)'));
```

Comment: this adds '.section:nth-child(5)' as a text-sting, not after that element.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the $() selector... I will edit this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Detach() instead of Remove() and then use InsertAfter()